# Write Genric function that takes function signature of varying length of argument as argument in type level

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, purescript

I want to create a function, that takes function as varying argument, the only thing i know about the funtion argument(which is a function itself) is they are wrapped in the same Monad....

```
myFunc :: forall arguments output m. 
                      MonadEffect m 
                   => (arguments -> m output)
                   ->  m (argument -> m output)
myFunc fn = do
            -- getting function's name using FFI and other stuff...
            pure fn
```

I'm able to write the function, when I explicitly specify the argument length like,

```
-- for function with ONE argument
myFunc1 :: forall argument1 output m
                   . MonadEffect m 
                   => (argument1 -> m output)
                   -> m (argument1 -> m output)
myFunc1 fn = do 
              -- do something 
              pure fn


-- for function with TWO argument
myFunc2 :: forall argument1 argument2 output m. 
                   MonadEffect m => 
                   (argument1 -> argument2 -> m output) ->
                   m (argument1 -> argument2 ->  m output)
myFunc2 fn = do 
             -- do something 
             pure fn
```

**How can I write `argument1 -> argument2 -> m output` as `argument -> m output` in type level?**

is there any type/Constraint that helps in doing so?

ps: I just want to understand whether it's possible

Comment: What do you imagine the implementation and use sites looking like? Why does the number of arguments to the function matter? It's hard to recommend something specific: without knowing details like these, the obvious implementation `myFunc = pure` is easy and has no obvious drawbacks.

Comment: I want to do some monadic `m` operation inside the generic function, it's decided by the output type of the function signature...

Comment: "getting function's name using FFI"? Uh, that doesn't sound good. A general function doesn't have a name in any reasonable sense, unless it happens to be defined on the top level – which many functions are of course, but very many aren't. If you want to manipulate names, you should pass a [`Name`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.19.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Name), which is completely agnostic WRT how many arguments the thing it refers to takes (or indeed whether it is a function at all). ...

Comment: ...OTOH, If you actually want to deal with functions, you should simply [`uncurry`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) them as needed to take exactly one argument. Or perhaps even remove the argument entirely from the signature, as it can also be wrapped into a suitable `ReaderT` on top of the monad.

Comment: I want to get the output type of a function of varying argument length, let's say my function has type `Int -> String -> Int -> Effect Unit` I want to store `Effect Unit` in type-level, can I do that? because if i have `forall arguments output. (arguments -> output)` , argument is inferred as `Int` and output is infered as `String -> Int -> Effect Unit` .... (because  of currying)... can we do something where `arguments` is infered as `Int -> String -> Int` and output as `Effect Unit`

Comment: Fundamentally, you're going to run into the problem that `a -> b -> c` is a function that takes one argument of type `a` and returns a single result of type `b -> c`.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, you can define type families that calculate the return type of a function:

```
type family Result f where
  Result (a -> b) = Result b
  Result b = b
```

and a type-level list of the types of its arguments (in reverse order):

```
type Arguments f = Arguments' '[] f
type family Arguments' args f where
  Arguments' args (a -> b) = Arguments' (a ': args) b
  Arguments' args b = args
```

This would allow you to write:

```
myFunc :: forall f arguments output m.
  ( Monad m
  , Result f ~ m output
  , Arguments f ~ arguments
  ) => f -> m f
myFunc fn = pure fn
```

which would make available type variables `output` and `arguments` within the body of your function:

```
myFunc :: forall f arguments output m.
  ( MonadIO m
  , Result f ~ m output
  , Arguments f ~ arguments
  , Typeable arguments, Typeable output
  ) => f -> m f
myFunc fn = do
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show (typeRep (Proxy @output))
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Arguments: " ++ show (typeRep (Proxy @arguments))
  pure fn
```

This may or may not be suitable for what you're trying to do, and it may or may not work in Purescript.

Anyway, here's a self-contained Haskell example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Typeable

type family Result f where
  Result (a -> b) = Result b
  Result b = b

type Arguments f = Arguments' '[] f
type family Arguments' args f where
  Arguments' args (a -> b) = Arguments' (a ': args) b
  Arguments' args b = args

myFunc :: forall f arguments output m.
  ( MonadIO m
  , Result f ~ m output
  , Arguments f ~ arguments
  , Typeable arguments, Typeable output
  ) => f -> m f
myFunc fn = do
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show (typeRep (Proxy @output))
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Arguments: " ++ show (typeRep (Proxy @arguments))
  liftIO . putStrLn $ ""
  pure fn

resultType :: forall f r. (Result f ~ r, Typeable r) => f -> String
resultType _ = show $ typeRep (Proxy @r)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- myFunc (pure . length :: String -> IO Int)
  _ <- myFunc ((\x y -> pure (x+y)) :: Double -> Double -> IO Double)
  putStrLn "done"
```

Comment: This answer is so elegant, but I wish we have type families in purescript...